# calling .name on checkbox in array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my function to add markers via google maps i want the title of the pin to be the name prop on the checkboxArray item and I can only seem to get undefined when i try .name i would love some feedback.

```
function addMarker() {
  console.log(checkboxArray[iterator].name)
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: things[iterator],
    map: map,
    title: checkboxArray[iterator].name,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }));
  iterator++;
}
```

when i `console.log(checkboxArray[iterator].name)` i get `undefined`
when i `console.log(checkboxArray[iterator])` i get `<option value="40.7002593,-111.7941413" name="French Fry" selected="" class="in">French Fry</option>`
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getAttribute()

```
checkboxArray[iterator].getAttribute("name");
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/y3s1277c/)

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to Help! :)